# How Can I Edit(Or Workaround) a C# anonymous type that is sent to rdlc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, rdlc

I have a project where I NEED to work with anonymous types. It's all good until I need to edit it. I tried with JSON and with ExpandoObject, but the method that uses that object seems to don't like them. That's how I populate my ExpandoObject:

```
                {
                    DataSources2.Add(entry.Key, new List<object>());
                    foreach (var item in entry.Value)
                    {
                        var obj = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
                        foreach (PropertyInfo s in item.GetType().GetProperties())
                        {
                            obj.Add(s.Name, s.GetValue(item));
                        }
                    }
                        dynamic dynamicObjedct = obj.Aggregate(new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>,
                                                     (a, p) => { a.Add(p); return a; });
                        var b = new List<object>() { dynamicObjedct };
                        DataSources2[entry.Key] = b;
                    }
```

The Dynamic View of this seems to dont like nulls as well. I dont know if this is making any difference in my problem, but oh well.
I am sending that anonymous to an rdlc that makes it into a pdf. Here is the line where it fails:

```
 <Visibility>
              <Hidden>=decimal.Parse(First(Fields!LoanAmount.Value, "ApplicationInfo")) &lt;= 25000</Hidden>
            </Visibility>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For that code you don't need an anonymous type, but until I know you can't do that with a report. But you can use reflection to know wich object you will work with the report before send the data

Comment: Well, the thing is that I am on an old project that has 10k ish lines written with anonymous type and I can't come and change that(I would like to tho). To work with that object, they used reflection to send the properties to the specific report.

Comment: For sure, reports are very limited and you need to know the types to complete the data.

Comment: I think it needs to know the properties of an object, not as much as to its type. I am kinda new to this so I might be wrong, but they generated reports like this with anonymous types for years.

Comment: Yes, of course. For that you can use also a model like MVC, so you have specifics objects for the report with well know properties.

Comment: Yes, I know what you are saying, but they already generated 100 or more anonymous types that they used with reflection in different parts of the code, and it would be almost impossible for me to refactor this whole code.

Comment: I Will follow this because is interesting, so far I know there is no way but for sure someone will have more head to think a workaround than me.